# In Scala, how do I perform additional string manipulation when using foreach on a List?

Tags: scala

For example to print everything I can do

```
list.foreach(println(_))
```

How would I do the equivalent of

```
list.foreach(println(_ + "mystring"))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to fix your second example you can name function argument like this:

```
list.foreach(x => println(x + "mystring"))
```

By the way, as alternative you can at first `map` your list and then print each element in it:

```
list map (_ + "mystring") foreach println
```

This will produce the same results.

Answer (score 4):

Just a bit of additional information to other two answers:

1. `list.foreach(println(_))` is basically short for `list.foreach(s => println(s))`.
2. `list.foreach(println(_ + "mystring"))` is syntactically correct, but it is equivalent to `list.foreach(println(s => s + "mystring"))` (and the compiler can't figure out what the type of `s` is) instead of what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can either declare a variable:

```
list.foreach(s => println(s + "mystring"))
```

or you can declare a method that does what you want, and then call that:

```
def myprint(s: String) = println(s + "mystring"))
list.foreach(myprint)
```